# WUC-11 Error when javascript raises event on applet

Tags: javascript, oracleforms

I get an error (**WUC-11**) when my JavaScript raises an event on my Oracle Forms applet.

According to Open JDK this bug should have been resolved, but I still get this error

> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037517

If anybody knows why this happens and/or knows a work-around, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WUC errors are errors coming from webutil. This means you are using webutil.
Before you can use webutil it gets registered. To do so it uses the frmwebutil.jar
This jar file needs to be signed with an official certificate (not just one created by you).